# Слово "мириады"

Tags: этимология

"Мириады" - говорят, когда хотят обозначить некое огромное, не поддающееся счету количество. А что это за слово? По звучанию напоминает "миллиарды".
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > МИРИА́ДЫ, мириад, ед. мириада, мириады, жен. (греч. myrias - десять тысяч) (книжн.). Великое, неисчислимое множество. Мириады насекомых. Мириады звезд.

Толковый словарь Ушакова.